# Fire Separation Wall - what should I use to seal small exposed openings?

Tags: sealing, fireproof

From recent home inspection:

FIRE SEPARATION WALL: Recommend sealing the small exposed openings at the low voltage wire penetrations at the garage ceiling above the garage door openers to maintain the garage fire separation wall.

[image]

Can someone please recommend what I should/can use to address it?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for a situation where the cable will never, ever have to be replaced, or something that can accommodate future cable replacements/upgrades?

Comment: I don't envision upgrading these cables (they are safety cables for garage opener).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestop - caulking or foam (there are other brands of both, just examples, not recommendations.)

These are helpful because they will seal around a cable as it melts in a fire (they expand with exposure to heat/flame) but the majority of the hole could also be addressed with plain old drywall compound (it seals all the other holes in the wall.) Using firestop around penetrations (such as the cable itself) is good practice, and some jurisdictions require more extensive approaches, such as an extended collar with fire sealant around cables, pipes and ducts.

[image: 3M Fire caulking] [image: Boss firestop foam]
[image: STI firestop grommet]